# Is sucking on one's own blood halal

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

Assalamu Alaikum

In case if a person gets hurt and bleeds , is it ok to suck on that blood or it is Haram?

Comment: blood is haram in islam....

Answer (score 2):

Drinking any kind of blood considered Haram in Islam,

> Allah says: Prohibited to you are dead animals, blood, the flesh of
> swine, and that which has been dedicated to other than
> Allah,...[[5,3]](http://quran.com/5/3)

[Arabic fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/96584)

But if there's a need to do it, like helping someone got hurt or something, it's OK but you have to spit it out. you can't swallow it.

Comment: not OK... if the wound is big take him/her to doctor's, or if it is minor cut, press there with thumb, it will help stop bleeding. blood contains germs, and donot take it in mouth

Comment: @MAKZ as i said if there's a need. not if he just want to. you don't know what is the situation. so you can't say that he can't do it. if someones life or health depends on it, it's haram to not do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well Islam forbids the consumption of blood because blood contains urine. But when there's bleeding in your own case, it is a natural impulse to suck that because saliva acts as a healing agent. However, you mustn't by all means prevent forcing out the blood so you could taste more. Also if one gets bitten by a snake or any other animal, their saliva might contain venom or disease carriers so it's okay for a second person to suck a great deal of blood from the spot, by mouth (has to be spitted out later, holding breath) or by draining.